# Movie about a kidnapped girl and a boy with a teddy bear

Tags: story-identification, movie

I don't remember much of it as I was watching with a friend sometime ago. The plot included a girl who was killed/kidnapped or missing. There was also a boy who had something like a Teddy bear which he spoke with and the bear would talk to him, and at some point another boy tries to kiss this kid. I don't remember much else but I always wanted to know the name of the movie.

Answer (score 3):

Might this be *[A. I. Artificial Intelligence](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212720/)*?  It features a robot child who has a talking robotic teddy bear.  The boy is initially created as a temporary replacement for a couple's critically ill child, who has been placed in suspended animation.  (The frozen child is a son, not a daughter, though.)

[image: Teddy bear]

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the movie you're referencing - *[Animals](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1298530/)* (2012)

> Pol is a teenager with a seemingly calm life. He lives with his brother, and is still in high school. However, Pol has a secret: Deerhoof, a cuddly teddy bear who thinks, moves around, and with whom he shares his best moments. Life goes on as normal until the arrival of Ikari, an enigmatic student who seems to be hiding something. Pol is fascinated by his new classmate and attracted to the dark side he harbors. An inexplicable death and a series of strange events will transform the meek student's routine into a fantastic adventure, which will take over their lives.

### Trailer

Comment: You should give attribution to the source(s) you quote. Not just here, but as a general rule.

Comment: I added a quick attribution and trailer. THere's a longer plot summary at http://www.spectacularoptical.ca/2013/07/ghost-stories-of-youth-animals-2012/, no kidnapping that I can see, but apparently (as per the trailer), there is a school shooting during which Laia , the primary female which Pol interacts with, is pounding on a pane of glass, trying to let Pol know about the shooting, which could be misconstrued as her being kidnapped.